# In windows10(1803), socket programming

Tags: windows, sockets, select

[image]

In windows10(1803), socket programming

As show in the picture, the client_socket is added to `Write` set and `Write.fd_count` is become 1. but after doing select, `Write.fd_count` is become 0 and `FD_ISSET(client_socket, &Write)` is return 0. In other words, `client_socket` is delete from `Write` set by `select()` function.

It seems no such bug in other windows version. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. The returned `fd_set` tells you which sockets were ready. Since no sockets were ready, the returned `fd_set`s are supposed to be empty. Imagine if you had two sockets you were checking for readability and `select` returned 1. If the socket that hadn't been ready wasn't removed from the `fd_set` on output, how would you know which socket had been ready?

Comment: Thanks very much! But how should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: @JasonWang What's the problem exactly? How is this a problem?